# Internal Redirect - PHP and .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

Good evening,
I wanted to know if it is possible to redirect a request to my page as http://test.diogo.me to the page with the content -> http://www.diogo.me/pages/test/ (this redirection must be internal... the browser should point to http://test.diogo.me).
I have been reading about .htaccess and I feel that this is the resolution for me. 

I have tried with the following code:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.diogo\.me [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.diogo\.me [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

The output is error 404 file not found :(
Am I going in the right track? 
Sorry about my expressing limitations. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code in your .htaccess and remove your existing lines from there:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.diogo\.me$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.diogo.me/pages/test/ [L,P]
```

Comment: Or you can replace the `R` with `P` to proxy, so browser still says http://test.diogo.me/

Comment: Thanks a lot @JonLin, edited my answer to use `P` instead of `R`.

Comment: Thanks for the support @anubhava and Jon Lin. This code doesn't work, so can it be something to do with the configuration of my server?

Comment: Provide some details like what behavior are you seeing? Also provide matching logs from access.log and error.log of Apache.

Comment: Both access.log and error.log are empty and it gives me a "server not found" exception on my browser :(

Comment: Wow `server not found` :) I have to ask: Are your domain registered domains? Is your web server even running? How can access.log and error.log be empty? There is something there even when its not taking any request.

Comment: It is up. The access.log is empty from things related to these tests. It has some requests to other pages,etc. :p my domain is actually diogomend.me. Thank you

Comment: Try changing `P` to `R` in the RewriteRule above and see if that works.

Comment: My htaccess is built by this code :
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.diogomend\.me$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.diogomend.me/index.html [L,R]
</IfModule>` .. and still doesn't work when i open with http://test.diogomend.me

Comment: diogomend.me is resolving to an A address but test.diogomend.me isn't even resolving to an A address.

Comment: for instance, i have created an entry in my cpanel for a folder called rolasdaportela: http://rolasdaportela.diogomend.me (now doesn't work because of the htaccess) -> http://rolasdaportela.pt

Comment: If you create a subdomain today it takes few hours at least to get it across the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the `/pages` part

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.diogo\.me [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.diogo\.me [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/%1/$1 [L]
```

Assuming the subdomains have the same document-root as the main domain.

Comment: My entire htaccess: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.diogomend\.me [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.diogomend\.me [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/%1/$1 [L]
</IfModule>` and it still doesn't work. The request doesn't even show on my access.log